# $\displaystyle\iiint_E (x²+y²) \;\mathrm{d}V$ where $E$ is the region between the spheres $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 4$ and $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 9$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

To be honest I'm not even too sure of what I'm integrating. I'm picturing two spheres touching each other, with a cylinder of two different radii going from the center of one to the other and I'm supposed to calculate the volume of the space inside the cylinder not occupied by the spheres. Is that correct?

[image]

I'm still stuck though, I don't really know how to start this.

EDIT - Accidentally wrote the wrong integral.

Comment: The region you're considering is a spherical shell: it is outside a sphere centered at the origin with radius 2 and inside a sphere centered at the origin with radius 3.

Comment: They don't touch each other; rather they are _concentric_, i.e. they both have the same center.  One is inside the other. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Please, do **not** change your question after a valid answer has been provided.  If you discover a mistake in your problem statement, then pose a new problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is well-known that the Cartesian coordinates may be retrieved from the spherical coordinates (radius r, inclination $\theta$, azimuth $\varphi$), where $r \in [0, \infty)$, $\theta \in [0, \pi]$, $\varphi \in [0, 2\pi)$, by:
$$x=r \, \sin\theta \, \cos\varphi \\
y=r \, \sin\theta \, \sin\varphi \\
z=r \, \cos\theta$$
The spheres are concentric, then $2\leq r\leq 3$, while
$$x^2+y^2=\left(r \sin\theta\cos\varphi\right)^2+\left(r \sin\theta\sin\varphi\right)^2=r^2\sin^2\theta$$
and
$$\mathrm{d}V=r^2 \sin \theta \,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}\varphi.$$
Then
$$\displaystyle\iiint_E (x²+y²) \;\mathrm{d}V=\int_2^3 \int_0^\pi\int_0^{2\pi}r^2\sin^2\theta \cdot r^2 \sin \theta d\varphi d\theta dr$$

Answer (score 2):

The spheres are concentric, so the integral is straightforward in spherical coordinates:

$$\int_2^3 dr \, r^6 \, \int_0^{\pi} d\theta \, \sin{\theta} \, \int_0^{2 \pi} d\phi \,  = \frac{4 \pi}{7} (3^7-2^7) = \frac{8236 \pi}{7}$$

Comment: NB This solution was posed before the OP edited the question.  I leave this as the answer to the original question.